# Admob banner, how to show only on home

Tags: admob, flutter

Im successfully showing the smart banner on footer and then dispose it. My problem is that is showing on all pages of the app.

My question is: How to show only on one page?

```
@override
 void initState() {
   super.initState();
   myBanner
   ..load().then((loaded) {
     if (loaded && this.mounted) {
       myBanner..show();
     }
   });

 }
```

Answer (score 15):

I found working solution from Github link [here](https://github.com/benadrasni/abherbs_flutter/blob/7aa024356c95e7d8d532e0dc47e8f16dd7a2280e/lib/ads.dart). The idea is quite simple.

1. First you need an Ads helper class. You can follow the link or see below.
2. Call `showBannerAd` inside `initState()` at the page that you want to show Ads.
3. Call `showBannerAd` like the following snippet after you pushed a page. This will show Ads again after you return back from the pushed page.

```
Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => EditPage())).then((value) {
                      Ads.showBannerAd();
                    });
```

4. Call `hideBannderAd` inside `initState()` at the pushed page that you don't want to show Ads. Then you are done.

**My Ads helper class**

```
import 'package:firebase_admob/firebase_admob.dart';

const String testDevice = 'YOUR_DEVICE_ID';

class Ads {
  static BannerAd _bannerAd;

  static void initialize() {
    FirebaseAdMob.instance.initialize(appId: FirebaseAdMob.testAppId);
  }

  static const MobileAdTargetingInfo targetingInfo = MobileAdTargetingInfo(
    testDevices: testDevice != null ? <String>[testDevice] : null,
    keywords: <String>['foo', 'bar'],
    contentUrl: 'http://foo.com/bar.html',
    childDirected: true,
    nonPersonalizedAds: true,
  );

  static BannerAd _createBannerAd() {
    return BannerAd(
      adUnitId: BannerAd.testAdUnitId,
      size: AdSize.banner,
      targetingInfo: targetingInfo,
      listener: (MobileAdEvent event) {
        print("BannerAd event $event");
      },
    );
  }

  static void showBannerAd() {
    if (_bannerAd == null) _bannerAd = _createBannerAd();
    _bannerAd
      ..load()
      ..show(anchorOffset: 0.0, anchorType: AnchorType.bottom);
  }

  static void hideBannerAd() async {
    await _bannerAd.dispose();
    _bannerAd = null;
  }
}
```

Comment: Huge thanks! Super easy. Another Flutter Hack but good enough workaround until the flutter team ads in tree native apps.

Answer (score 1):

If you have multiple widgets acting as individual screens you just include the part

```
@override void initState() { 
    super.initState(); 
    myBanner ..load().then((loaded) { 
        if (loaded && this.mounted) { 
            myBanner..show(); 
        } 
    }); 
}
```

You probably need to dispose it:

```
@override
  void dispose() {
    myBanner?.dispose();
    super.dispose();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but that's my question. The banner is showing on all pages once its initialized, even through that code is only on one page.

Comment: im navigating to other pages through
'() => Navigator.push(context, new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => new NewPage()'

Comment: When your new Screen is called within the Navigator you just include the Banner into the start of the specific screen. Please share a bit more code of one of your screens.

Comment: as i said the problem is simple. once the banner is initialized it will show on all screens regardless where is initialized. Well let me give you my code

Comment: It will show on all screens that are under the position in the widget tree of where you initialized that banner.

Comment: no even if i put on a child screen, it will not show on homepage but once its initialized it will show again on all screen including homepage

Comment: so my question is simple, how to show just on one screen?

Comment: Yes but the initial code you posted shows the banner ad at the widget you put in your code. So you need to put thar widget at the position you want it at.

Comment: BannerAdd is not a widget btw.

Comment: You probably need to dispose it before you start a new screen.

Comment: of course i'm disposing it, but anyway thnx for trying. i will see if i find why is showing on all screens. again thnx

Comment: It could be that it is just not supported yet. But I figured out you can try to create the Banner myBanner inside the state of your app so it may be destroyed when you change to a new screen.

Comment: Just tried it: you can call myBanner?.dispose(); before you call the next screen. You may want to look at the WillPopScope too.

Comment: did you manage to show only one screen? if so please post a gist. i would much appreciate it

Comment: @AlvinKonda Something like this: https://gist.github.com/bostrot/3cc3cdb85706bdbb3f1b274bb66d6ca5

Comment: Well, it doesn't feel right, plus when you go back to main screen the banner will not show and also normally the other screen is on another file. Anyway thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Yes, that is a gist file. You can of course put the screen in another file. This is just to show you what I meant what you could do. Of course you have to do some extra work.

Comment: Yes but you are dispossing `_bannerAd` on ther other screen, which anyway i suppose is wrong as its not init on the current screen

Comment: any solution to this? I am also looking for answers for the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I just encountered the same problem while adding Ads to my app. In my case, I was calling my method to show the banner ad in the `didChangeDependencies` function. This method can be called multiple times by the app and I discovered (in my app) that it is called when you push a new route to the `Navigator` that's why a call to show the banner is made as I move to other screens of my app. Maybe you have a similar implementation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use await to wait for pop of second page

```
   bannerAd.dispose();
await Navigator.pushNamed(context, f['route']);
       intialzeAdd();
```

intialiazeAdd is called after the pop of second sceen

Answer (score 0):

call

```
Navigator.pop();
```

before calling `Navigator.push()`. This will solve your problem